# Writing a file using for loop. But I am not able to do it

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, filewriter

I have to write some data to files. I tried to write data to files using loops. But When I used this code it writes just one line per file.

help me with this code

```
               Vector[] v = jca.getClusterOutput();
    for (int i=0; i<v.length; i++)
    {
        Vector tempV = v[i];
        System.out.println("-----------Cluster"+i+"---------");
        Iterator iter = tempV.iterator();



        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            File file = new File("e://filename"+i+".txt");   
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            DataPoint dpTemp = (DataPoint)iter.next();
            System.out.println(dpTemp.getObjName()+"["+dpTemp.getX()+","+dpTemp.getY()+"]");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("\n"+dpTemp.getObjName()+"["+dpTemp.getX()+","+dpTemp.getY()+"]");

            //bw.close();
            bw.flush();

            System.out.println("Done");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new file each time you loop. Put the File file = new File(...); higher up.

Comment: I tried but still printing the same

Comment: You need to put it outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're overwriting the file in every iteration. Move the file creation, writer creation etc. out of the loop:

```
File file = new File("e://filename"+i+".txt");   
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

while(iter.hasNext())
{           
        DataPoint dpTemp = (DataPoint)iter.next();
        System.out.println(dpTemp.getObjName()+"["+dpTemp.getX()+","+dpTemp.getY()+"]");

        bw.write("\n"+dpTemp.getObjName()+" ["+dpTemp.getX()+","+dpTemp.getY()+"]");                        
}
//bw.close();
bw.flush();
System.out.println("Done");
```

Alternatively, you could recreate the `FileWriter` and pass `true` as the second constructor parameter, in order to append to the file instead of replacing its content. However, I'd sill recommend creating the writer only once.